# Имеется последовательность из N целых. Напишите программу, подсчитывающую и выводящую на экран сумму только тех чисел, которые оканчиваются на 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пример 1:

```
6
13
7
-5
0
-23
20
```

Результат:

```
-10
```

```
n = int(input()) 
sum = 0 
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input()) 
    if a % 10 == 3:
        sum += a    
print(sum)
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему у меня выводится 13, а не -10?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `-23 % 10` не пробовали посчитать?

Comment: замените `if a % 10 == 3:` на `if abs(a) % 10 == 3:`

Comment: В питоне остаток от деления отрицательных чисел работает контринтуитивно )

Answer (score 0):

Наверное потому, что остаток от деления на 10 у -23 будет -3, а не 3. Думаю, нужно взять модуль. Попробуйте так, если правильно понял:

```
n = int(input())
sum = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    if abs(a) % 10 == 3:
        sum += a
print(sum)
```